# Android Geofence triggers on enter/exit with no error but no GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ flag

Tags: android, android-geofence, google-location-services

I am monitoring for geofence transition using the code below

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi
    .addGeofences(AssistApplication.getApiHelper().getClient(),
                  getGeofencingRequest(),
                  getPendingIntent(context,  
                              GeofenceTransitionIntentService.class))
    .setResultCallback(this);
```

This is how I build the GeofencingRequest

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest()
{
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER |
                    GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)
            .addGeofence(getGeofence())
            .build();
}

private Geofence getGeofence()
{
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(requestId)
            .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, 100)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                    Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build();
}
```

The Geofence triggers correctly on enter and exit, but when I use `getGeofenceTransition()`, I am not getting any of the three `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_` flags.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    final GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (event.hasError())
    {
        Log.e(TAG, getErrorMessage(event.getErrorCode()));
        return;
    }

    switch (event.getGeofenceTransition())
    {
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
            // Not triggered 
            break;
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
            // Not triggered
            break;
        default:
            // Triggered on exit and enter
    }
}
```

please advise on what I am missing here

Comment: What are you setting in your `GeofencingRequest.Builder`? What ARE you getting back from `getGeofenceTransition()`? If it's -1 then your intent isn't from a transition alert. Are your Geofence events being received in a Broadcast Receiver?

Comment: I added the code where I build the request. I am setting `INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER` and `INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT` for initial trigger and `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER` and `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT` for transition. I am not getting any of the `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_` flags, so it must be -1 according to the API reference, but I know it's triggered with no error because the `default` code is executed when I enter/exit the region. If it's not a transition alert and no error, then what triggers the service? I am not using any broadcast receiver only the `IntentService`

Answer (score 2):

From the information in the question, I can't see any specific problems with your code, but I suspect the `Intent` you are processing isn't from a transition alert?

Personally I use a broadcast receiver to receive the `Intent` from the Geofence, with an `IntentFilter` used 
to filter it. The structure I use is as follows :-

Declare broadcast receiver in your `Activity`

```
private BroadcastReceiver passedGeofenceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int geofenceTransition;

            // get the Geofencing Event
            GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
            if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
                return;
            }

            // Get the transition type.
            geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

            if ( geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
                // etc etc
```

Register this receiver in your `Activity` `onCreate` method :-

```
    // register this Activity as the receiver of Geofence notifications
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.example.HIT_GEOFENCE");
    this.registerReceiver(this.passedGeofenceReceiver, filter);
```

On creation of a broadcast `PendingIntent`, set filter  (mGeofencePendingIntent is a member `PendingIntent` variable) :-

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }

    Intent hitGeofenceIntent = new Intent("com.example.HIT_GEOFENCE"); //- intent to send a broadcast

    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, hitGeofenceIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}
```

Monitor your geofences :-

```
private void monitorGeofences() {
    if ( <check permissions> ) {
        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = getGeofencingRequest();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = getGeofencePendingIntent();
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, geofencingRequest, pendingIntent)
                        .setResultCallback(this); // Result callback fires 'onResult'
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The activity is not active at the time the geofence transition happens, and I don't want it to start. I just want to show a notification. Will that still work?

Comment: How is your app structured? You can have a broadcast receiver as an independent class or else declare it within a service. I would suggest that if you're just waiting for a Geofence to trigger without having an Activity running, then you write it as a Broadcast Receiver app component. Sorry my answer wasn't useful.

Comment: I am working on a different project right now, so I haven't tried your answer yet. Will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue working with geofences on Android 12. No transition (-1), no triggering location and no triggering geofences in the intent.

That was because I was using `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` instead of `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` when creating the pending intent.

So it should be created like this in the case of a broadcast intent:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    context, 0,
    Intent(context, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or
        (if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE else 0)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added a post below about what issue I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

@Jukurrpa, I was facing the same issue, i.e., No transition(-1) or `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_INVALID_TYPE: -1` and I implemented everything correctly except the `flags` for `PendingIntent`.
I was using:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
else
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

Your answer helped me a lot, I was searching for the solution for the last 4 days. Thank you so much.